# Is there anyway that I can use Yup.js to validate sorted array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, yup

I'm working with form and using Yup.js for validation in my form. However, I have a problem when I want to check whether an array is sorted.

My array is look like this:

```
[
{
    date: "1970-01-01",
    money: 10
},
{
    date: "1970-01-02",
    money: 20
},
{
    date: "1970-01-03",
    money: 30
},
]
```

Comment: *I have a problem when I want to check whether an array is sorted* - what is the problem you have?

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't know how to use Yup.js validate this properly.